# no package ipset available (centos EL5 x86_64)

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos5, ipset

I want to install ipset, but none of my repos seem to have it when I run

```
yum install ipset

[root@ora1 /]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

[root@ora1 yum.repos.d]# ls

CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Media.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo  public-yum-el5.repo

[root@ora1 yum.repos.d]# uname -a

Linux ora1 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 04:16:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your iptables is probably wont work properly, i dont remember exactly what you need to do on EL5 with this kernel/iptables.
i know that packages from here worked for me:

```
http://mirror.ukrnames.com/mirrors/centalt/repository/centos/5/x86_64/ipset-4.5-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
http://mirror.ukrnames.com/mirrors/centalt/repository/centos/5/x86_64/iptables-1.3.5-5.6.1.el5.x86_64.rpm
http://mirror.ukrnames.com/mirrors/centalt/repository/centos/5/x86_64/kmod-ipset-4.5-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

or go here:
http://pkgs.org/centos-5/flexbox-x86_64/ipset-4.5-1.el5.x86_64.rpm.html

Requires:

```
ipset-kmod
iptables >= 1.3.5
```

Comment: `ipset` and `kmod-ipset` packages worked for me. Had to recompile the `iptables` to get it to work with ipset. I used version 1.4.7. A straight `./configure`, `make` and `make install` worked fine out of the box.